# Use Route model binding in service provider

Tags: php, laravel

I bind a model to a route parameter in `RouteServiceProvider.php`, like this:

```
Route::bind('page', function ($page) {
    return Page::whereSlug($page)->first();
});
```

In `config/app.php`, I've added another service provider with the following (after RouterServiceProvider):

`App\Providers\ContentServiceProvider::class`

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->singleton(ContentProvider::class, function() {
         // Route::current()->parameters();
    });
}
```

**How can I access resolved page model in my service provider?**